# When increase transaction fee three times in few minutes - transaction had an attempted double-spent?

Tags: bitcoin-core

I make transaction from my wallet - send BTC.
After I send, I increase transaction fee three times, in a few minutes.

Now I see - Status: conflicted with a transaction with 21 confirmations

I use Bitcoin Core version v0.18.1 (64-bit)

In block explorer I see that this transaction had an attempted double-spent.

What can do in my case?

Answer (score 3):

The double spend attempt *is* your fee increase. It is impossible to modify a transaction after it has been broadcast. So to increase the fee, your wallet intentionally creates a double spend of it that has a higher transaction fee.

However it isn't just a pure double spend; there are additional conditions the original transaction and its double spend must meet before nodes will replace the original. When you increase the transaction fee, the wallet checks that the original transaction met certain rules, then it creates the double spend to meet the replacement rules.

The wallet should recognize that the original transaction has been replaced, but if it does not, you should be able to force it to. Because the replacement confirmed, you should be able to right click on the original transaction entry and choose the "abandon transaction" option to keep it out of balance calculations other things. It will remain in your transaction history, but have no effect on anything.

Answer (score 2):

Increasing the transaction fee is literally trying to replace the transaction. Some sites will detect that as an "attempted double spend" - it literally is, but in this case it is desirable.